# incrementing a number in bash with leading 0

Tags: bash, shell, variables, if-statement

I am a very newbie to bash scripting and am trying to write some code to parse and manipulate a file that I am working on.

I need to increment and decrement the minute of a time for a bunch of different times in a file.  My problem happens when the time is for example 2:04 or 14:00.

File Example:

```
2:43
2:05
15:00
```

My current excerpt from my bash script is like this

```
for x in `cat $1`;
  do minute_var=$(echo $x | cut -d: -f2);
  incr_min=$(($minute_var + 1 | bc));
  echo $incr_min;
done
```

Current Result:

```
44
6
1
```

Required Result:

```
44
06
01
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Even in bash, a good practice is to separate view and model. The way numbers are displayed should not interfere with the way they are incremented.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it okay for 59 to increment to 60, or should it wrap to 00?

Comment: No need for expensive pipes an forks: `minute_var=${x#*:}` removes everything upto and including the first `:`.

Comment: @Jens: Even `${x#*:}` can be skipped using `while IFS=: read hr min; do`. The minutes will be read to `min` directly. And no external utility needs to be used (no `cat`, `cut` or `bc`).

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf`:

```
incr_min=$(printf %02d $(($minute_var + 1 )) )
```

No that `bc` is not needed if only integers are involved.

Comment: Actually `printf` also an external utility. Also not needed in this case.

Comment: You're going to hit octal issues -- test with the time "8:08". You need `$((10#$minute_var + 1 ))`

Comment: @TrueY, `printf` is a bash builtin -- see `type -a printf`

Comment: @glennjackman: Yepp! You are right! Thanks for the info! Maybe instead of `incr_min=$(printf...)` the `printf -v incr_min ...` could be used.

Comment: @glennjackman: I tested with strace. In case of `$(printf ...)` a `clone` is called to create a child process every time. If `printf -v ...` is used then no child is created. So the later uses less resources.

Answer (score 1):

is this ok for your requirement?

```
kent$  echo "2:43
2:05
15:00"|awk -F: '{$2++;printf "%02d\n", $2}'
44
06
01
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED #2**

There are some problems with your script. At first instead of `` `cat file` `` you should use  `` `<file` `` or rather `$(<file)`. One `fork` and `exec` call is spared as `bash` simply opens the file. On the other hand calling `cut` and `bc` (and `printf`) also not needed as `bash` has internally the proper features. So you can spare some `fork`s and `exec`s again.

If the input file is large (greater then cca 32 KiB) then the `for`-loop line can be too large to be processed by `bash` so I suggest to use `while`-loop instead and read the file line-by-line.

I could suggest something like this in pure `bash` (applied Atle's substr solution):

```
while IFS=: read hr min; do
  incr_min=$((1$min+1)); #Octal problem solved
  echo ${incr_min: -2}; #Mind the space before -2!
  #or with glennjackman's suggestion to use decimal base
  #incr_min=0$((10#$min+1))
  #echo ${incr_min: -2};
  #or choroba's solution improved to set variable directly
  #printf -v incr_min %02d $((10#$min+1))
  #echo $incr_min
done <file
```

Input file

```
$ cat file
2:43
2:05
15:00
12:07
12:08
12:09
```

Output:

```
44
06
01
08
09
10
```

Maybe the `printf -v` is the simplest as it puts the result to the variable in a single step.

Good question from `tripleee` what should happen if the result is 60.

Comment: You're going to hit octal issues -- test with the time "8:08". You need `$((10#${x#*:}+1))`

Comment: @glennjackman: You are absolutely right! Thanks for it! Answer corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=: read hour min; do 
    printf "%02d\n" $((10#$min + 1))
done <<END
2:43
2:05
15:00
8:08
0:59
END
```

```
44
06
01
09
60
```

For the minute wrapping to the next hour, use a language with time functions, like gawk

```
awk -F: '{
    time = mktime("1970 01 01 " $1 " " $2 " 00")
    time += 60
    print strftime("%M", time)
}'
```

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -nle '
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%H:%M");
    print +($t + ONE_MINUTE)->strftime("%M");
'
```

Comment: Good point. You _could_ implement the wrapping logic yourself in bash, but it'd miss the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to reformat the output to be zero-padded, 2-wide:

```
incr_min=$(printf %02d $incr_min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that

- wraps the seconds from 59 to 0
- is fully POSIX compliant--no bashisms!
- doesn't need a single fork thus is extremely fast

```
$ cat x
2:43
2:05
2:08
2:09
15:00
15:59
$ while IFS=: read hr min; do
   printf '%02d\n' $(((${min#0}+1)%60))
done < x
44
06
09
10
01
00
```

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks; it worked in zsh; fixed to work in any Bourne shell like bash which would complain about `08: value too great for base (error token is "08")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in $(<$1); do
    printf "%02d\n" $(((${x#*:}+1)%60));
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Padding with 0, and getting two last characters:

```
for x in `cat $1`;
  do minute_var=$(echo $x | cut -d: -f2);
  incr_min=0$(($minute_var + 1 | bc));
  echo ${incr_min: -2:2};
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the `${::}` idea. But not needed to call any external utilities, like `cat`, `cut` and `bc`.

Comment: Doesn't quote when it needs to, has a lot of unnecessary pipelines, ignores built-in shell functionality that does the job better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, what I did was modifying the code in the original question to show a way of solving the problem. My modifications are using built in shell functionality, and does not use pipes. And even if they did, there is nothing wrong at all with using different tools together to solve problems. In fact, that is the *nix way.

Comment: @Atle Piping to `bc` is using an external tool for what was previously done internal to bash. Because it's in a subshell, it requires a `fork()` call, an `exec()`, a `read()`, etc., and is otherwise vastly inefficient. The UNIX way involves using many tools that operate on the same (stream) interface, yes -- but it is not an excuse for inefficiency.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My solution isn't using piping to bc. My solution is to pad the start of the string with a 0, and then use {: -2:2} to extract the last part of the variable. What you're commenting on here is the original code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also 'efficiency' is your peeve, not a requirement in the question. Nobody needs an excusion not to be optimally efficient when efficiency is not a requirement. Most *nix systems handles wasting a few cycles creating and destroying processes very well.

Comment: @Atle Not just _my_ peeve. Take that code to freenode's #bash and see what folks think.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Having the code evaluated by totally different criteria than that of the original posters is of absolutely no relevance here. And again: The solution I provided is not equal to the full code. I demonstrated how to pad and extract. That solution is not bad just because I used it within the context already given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The idea of policing solutions based on your personal (or some forums) criteria is just bad manners. Instead you should point out actual errors, provide explanations, demonstrate improvements and other options; generally teach others how to do things smarter.

Comment: Hmm. Actually -- for the minute value in a time, this is at least going to give correct results. For something where a valid value could use more than two digits, you'd want to use `printf -v padded_value %02d "$value_to_pad"` instead. That said, I absolutely do not accept a premise that giving correct results is the only thing necessary to be an acceptable answer; following best practices matters.

Comment: (To be clear on why following this pattern could lead to incorrect results in other use cases -- think truncation).